# Have to open in same Activity while clicking menubar

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two  java classes. `MainActivity` and `DisplayActivity`.

In MainActivity I used to display some data and have a `menu bar` at the top which is a SEE MORE(overflow menu item) and while clicking on SEE MORE I display some `data` in DisplayActivity in which it have a `recyclerview`. And while clicking on any item in the recyclerView present in DisplayActivity it will display the MainActivity.

**problem :**
But  when every time  menu item(SEEMORE) in MainActivity or recyclerView item is clicked `new Activities` are loading. But i need to display details in same Activity instead of loading new Activity every time when I click.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can help us with showing your code?

Comment: Why don't you create Dialogue fragment?On the behalf of recycler view row click, you dissmiss the dialogue and load the data on Mainactivity. This will not load your activity rather it will resume.

Comment: @Anu Rapheal, as this question is about UI, why don't you show us 2 pictures, one with what you want to have, the other with what you actually have? It helps us way more than reading text trying to figure out what you mean

Comment: please show your code so we can help you out

Comment: Since the code and UI is confidential i cannot disclose here. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `launchMode` of your activity in your `AndroidManifest` to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

Then in the same activity, override the `onNewIntent` method and put your code there.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Show something else on the UI from this method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a fragment or dialog。
1、Create a fragment to replace Activity
2、Change Activity theme to Theme.AppCompat.Dialog